# Information about Bootstrap 4 class ".dual-collapse2"

Tags: bootstrap-4

Hello I have never seen a documentation about ".dual-collapse2" and I've seen that people use this class in different examples like this one:
[Re-positioning items on navbar collapse in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390642/re-positioning-items-on-navbar-collapse-in-bootstrap?rq=1&fbclid=IwAR2zDEgbFoAiR3wIMukpsan9spWNaZHMKguwA8pdTipfH1V-uNCWbaTB64Y)

Can someone explain since there is no info for such a class in the official documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello so with the help of other forums I conclude that this is a custom class added from the code writer, used instead ID - the user adds this class wherever he wants a div to be collapsed and then uses

```
data-target=".dual-collapse2"
```

Comment: to add on this: it is used for a collapsible navbar that contains 2 parts - 1 on the left and 1 on the right. Because we have 2 elements that we have to adress, we can not use an id for it