# Re-position logo and burger menu on collapsed navbar with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Using react-bootstrap I have a logo on the left and the menu items on the right.
When collapsing the burger menu appears on the right side as expected.

I am trying to reposition the items on collapse and have the **burger menu on the left** and the **logo at the center**.

This question seems appropriate: [Re-positioning items on navbar collapse in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390642/re-positioning-items-on-navbar-collapse-in-bootstrap)
However I can't replicate the effect because I am using react-bootstrap and the syntax is very different.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, Container  } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../assets/WT_JustLogo_White.png';
import './CustomNavbar.scss';

class CustomNavbar extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <Navbar sticky="top" expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
       <Container>
         <Navbar.Brand>
           <Link to="/">
             <img src={logo}
               className="Nav-logo"
               alt="logo"
             />
           </Link>
         </Navbar.Brand>
         <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
         <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
           <Nav className="ml-auto">
             <Nav.Item>
               <Nav.Link className="menuLink" eventKey={1}>
                 <Link className="text-light menuText" to="/">HOME</Link>
             </Nav.Link>  
             </Nav.Item>
             <Nav.Item>
               <Nav.Link className="menuLink" eventKey={3}>
                 <Link className="text-light menuText" to="/About">ABOUT</Link>
             </Nav.Link>  
             </Nav.Item>
             <Nav.Item>
               <Nav.Link className="menuLink" eventKey={4}>
                 <Link className="text-light menuText" to="/Contact">CONTACT</Link>
             </Nav.Link>  
             </Nav.Item>
           </Nav>
         </Navbar.Collapse>
       </Container>
     </Navbar>
   );
 }
}

export default CustomNavbar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use order like this:
add order-1 to brand with mx-auto:

```
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home" className="order-md-0 mx-auto order-1">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
```

add order-0 to nav collapse:

```
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="-navbar-nav"  className="order-md-1 order-0"/>
```

Comment: This works well, but adds a middle step where the burger menu first appears on the right side and then move to the left at a smaller screen. I changed 'order-md' to 'order-lg' on both the logo and the toggle and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: testing it, I just notice that ordering the items has drawback: when expanding the menu, the logo is pushed down. Can I make the logo stay on the top of the page when the menu expands or cover the logo completely?

Comment: yes man its normal if you can see the collapse is changing display from none to block